# Automator service to create Dropbox symlink

Tags: macos, finder, automator, dropbox, symlink

I'm trying to create an Automator service(in the right click menu) that creates a symlink of the folder/file and moves it to the Dropbox folder. This is what I have right now:

```
while [ $# -ne 0 ]; do
    ln -s "$1" "$1 symlink"
    mv "$1 symlink" ~/Dropbox/.
    shift
done
```

However what I want to do is create a folder with the same name ($1). Trying `mv "$1 symlink" ~/Dropbox/"$1"` doesn't work. I can't seem to figure out how to rename the folder. I tried this, and for some reason, it moved the symlink folder to inside the folder it was symlinking($1).

```
while [ $# -ne 0 ]; do
    loc = "~/Dropbox"
    ln -s "$1" "$1 symlink"
    mv "$1 symlink" "$loc/$1"
    shift
done
```